# Boost serialization polymorphic register(export) not working across files

Tags: boost, boost-serialization

I am using `boost::serialization` in my project. The project is large, and serializes  my objects in several places. According to the [documentation here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html#export), I should export my class with two separated step.

1. `BOOST_EXPORT_KEY()` in `.h` file, witch contains the declaration.
2. `BOOST_EXPOET_IMPLEMENT()` in `.cpp` file, witch contains the instantiation(definition) of the exporting.

`hier.h` the class hierarchy, there are 3 classes in the hierarchy.

```
/*
B <---+--- D1
      |
      +--- D2
*/

#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>                                                                                                                                                                 

class B {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    virtual ~B() {}                                                                                                                                                                                            
    template < typename Ar >                                                                                                                                                                                   
    void serialize(Ar& ar, const int) {                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
} ;                                                                                                                                                                                                            

class D1 : public B {                                                                                                                                                                                          
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    virtual ~D1() {}                                                                                                                                                                                           
    template < typename Ar > void serialize(Ar& ar, const int) {                                                                                                                                               
        boost::serialization::base_object<B>(*this);                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
} ;                                                                                                                                                                                                            

class D2 : public B {                                                                                                                                                                                          
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    template < typename Ar > void serialize(Ar& ar, const int) {                                                                                                                                               
        boost::serialization::base_object<B>(*this);                                                                                                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    virtual ~D2() {}                                                                                                                                                                                           
} ;                                                                                                                                                                                                            

#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>                                                                                                                                                                      

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(B);                                                                                                                                                                                     
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(D1);                                                                                                                                                                                    
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(D2);
```

And a `hier.cpp` contains the implementation:

```
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include "hier.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(D1);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(D2);
```

And a `main.cpp` use the serialization:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                            
#include <sstream>                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>                                                                                                                                                                     
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>                                                                                                                                                                      
#include "hier.h"                                                                                                                                                                                              

int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    B* d1 = new D1();                                                                                                                                                                                          
    B* d2 = new D2();                                                                                                                                                                                          
    std::ostringstream os;                                                                                                                                                                                     
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa (os);                                                                                                                                                                     
    oa & d1 & d2;                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

It compiled without any problem, but run it will cause:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  unregistered class - derived class not registered or exported
```

Which means the derived class is not registered, means the registration in the `hier.cpp` is not working. But that is really strange, because:

1. If I register implementation is both `main.cpp` and `hier.cpp`, it issue duplicated definition while linking. **Means the registration in `hier.cpp` is OK and is exposed into the linkers visibility.**, otherwise there will be no duplicated definition error.
2. If I register implementation only in `main.cpp`, it runs OK.

I am really confused in that situation. Any comment and suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before calling `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_*` you should include the archives which you want to use. The maсro then adds specific serialize-functions for the headers.

This means you should change your code in `hier.cpp` to the following:

```
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include "hier.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(D1);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(D2);
```

The code in `hier.h` changes accordingly:

```
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(B);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(D1);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(D2);
```

Sources:
[Boost Serialization Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export)

PS:
I do not know if this is solving your problem, but I think it could be causing some trouble. I think it's worth a try.

Comment: This is by far the clearest and most useful question and answer on Boost serialization I've found to date.  Like much of Boost's other docs, the serialization docs are a wandering quagmire of information, and this simple example is very concise, and helped me solve my issue.  Well done!

Comment: The right solution after so many years... My problem was the order of header files... Even if in my opinion #include order should never matter in a source file...