# function template specialization ignored by the compiler

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, boost, template-specialization

Our project uses boost::serialization to serialize many things.
But some types are not correctly registered and when serializing them we get an "unregistered class" error
I have narrowed the problem to the BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY, which, for some types are not generating code.
What BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY does is :

```
namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {
        template<>
        struct guid_defined< T > : boost::mpl::true_ {};
        template<>
        inline const char * guid< T >(){
            return K;
        }
    } /* serialization */
} /* boost */
```

All objects that are serialized inherit from a base class called Serializable.
Serialization is always done via a pointer to the base class.

This works fine except for one case:
There is a class template SerializableList which is a Serializable which holds a list of T

```
template< typename T>
class SerializableList
{
    ...
    std::vector<T> m_list;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize( Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/ )
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<businessObjects::Serializable>(*this);
        ar & mList;
    }
};
```

in a dedicated cpp and hpp files we then declare each instantiation of this template to boost serialization like this:

hpp:

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY( SerializableList<SomeT*> );
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY( SerializableList<SomeOtherT*> );
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY( SerializableList<AThirdT*> );
```

cpp:

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT( SerializableList<SomeT*> );
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT( SerializableList<SomeOtherT*> );
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT( SerializableList<AThirdT*> );
```

But half of these lines do not produce executable code in the final executable! if we put a breakpoint on each of those lines and run, half the breakpoints disappear, those who stay are on the working types (those we can serialize).
For instance the breakpoints would stay on `SerializableList<SomeT*>` and `SerializableList<AThirdT*>` but not `SerializableList<SomeOtherT*>`.

Btw, we have also tried to call directly `boost::serialization::guid<T>()`, and while it works fine for say:
`boost::serialization::guid<SerializableList<SomeT*> >()` which returns the key,
it doesn't for 
`boost::serialization::guid<SerializableList<SomeOtherT*> >()` which calls the default implementation ...

**So is there a compiler bug (we use Visual C++ 2010 SP1), or some good reason for the compiler to ignore some of those specializations?**

I forgot to mention, all this code lies in a library, which is linked against the exe project. I've tried with different exe projects and sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't ... the compilation options are the same... I really have **no clue** what's going on :'(

Comment: Have you try to explicit instantiate the (missing) classes: `template class SerializableList<SomeOtherT*>;` ?

Comment: "*I forgot to mention, all this code lies in a library*" This might be the problem. Is it a static or dynamic library? (I'll try to find similar questions, as IIRC this problem has been described before on SO)

Comment: [boost docs:](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html) *"Placing `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` in library code will have no effect unless archive class headers are also included. So when building a library, one should include all headers for all the archive classes which he anticipates using. Alternatively, one can include headers for just the Polymoprhic Archives."* (Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7875107/420683)

Comment: @dyp it is a static library. I'm aware of your quote the archives are included above. And it works for 6 types out of 13 ... in the same file

Comment: After looking into the boost sources, I think I once had a similar problem. Have you tried compiling+using it as a DLL? (using load-time linking)

Comment: Also, you could try `/OPT:NOREF` (properties->linker->optimization) or exporting/importing the variable created by `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT`

Comment: I've already tried /OPT:NOREF. the IMPLEMENT part works fine, I can put a breakpoint on it and it does break uppon startup. The part which randomly works is the EXPORT_KEY part

Comment: Hmm could you then create a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) so that I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I've tried but I can't reproduce the same bug :/

Comment: If you add a `@username` in a comment, [the user will be notified](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Owners of an answer/post will automatically be notified. -- If you're lucky, you might now find the bug in the difference between the SSCCE and your actual program :) (stay optimistic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution,

One (serializable) class had several SerializableList members, and did not include the file with all the "`BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY`" lines.

the other projects which were working didn't use that particular class ...