# Boost serialize boost::array failed

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying the examples of this link: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.serialization-wrappers

But the example that directly serialize boost::array compile failed:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost::archive;

std::stringstream ss;

void save()
{
  text_oarchive oa{ss};
  boost::array<int, 3> a{{0, 1, 2}};
  oa << a;
}

void load()
{
  text_iarchive ia{ss};
  boost::array<int, 3> a;
  ia >> a;
  std::cout << a[0] << ", " << a[1] << ", " << a[2] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  save();
  load();
}
```

A part of error code shows like:

```
In files included from /usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37:0,
/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/archive/detail/oserialzer.hpp:39,
/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23,
/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22,
/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp:29,
/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:31,
from test.cpp:1:

/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In instantiation of 'static void boost:serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = boost_array<int, 3ul>]':
/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:68:69: required from 'void boost:serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = boost_array<int, 3ul>]'
/usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:126:23: required from 'void boost:serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = boost_array<int, 3ul>]'
..................
test.cpp:15:9: required from here
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:116:9: error: 'class boost::array<int, 3ul>' has no member named serialize'
   t.serialize(ar, file_version);
   ^
```

**My system config:
Ubuntu 18.04 + Boost 1.65.1**

I've been tried my manually installed boost 1.65.1 in the lib path /usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/ and system installed boost 1.65.1 in the lib path /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
Unfortunately, both of the libraries compiled failed as the same error.

But if the boost array use wrapper function boost::serialization::make_array(),
It will compile OK and works.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace boost::archive;

std::stringstream ss;

void save()
{
  text_oarchive oa{ss};
  std::array<int, 3> a{{0, 1, 2}};
  oa << boost::serialization::make_array(a.data(), a.size());
}

void load()
{
  text_iarchive ia{ss};
  std::array<int, 3> a;
  ia >> boost::serialization::make_array(a.data(), a.size());
  std::cout << a[0] << ", " << a[1] << ", " << a[2] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  save();
  load();
}
```

or I manually change the line

```
oa << a;
```

and

```
ia >> a;
```

to

```
oa << boost::serialization::make_array(a.data(), a.size());
```

and

```
ia >> boost::serialization::make_array(a.data(), a.size());
```

It will compile OK too.

Comment: The `make_array` wrapper is intended to wrap /any/ contiguous array of elements, but the `boost::array` support is intended such that you don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global variable `ss` raises red flags. Sharing in that way may have unintended consequences:

- for one, residu content maybe remain
- more subtly, there might not be a flush when required.

Besides that, it looks like you're missing the include for array serialization:

```
#include <boost/serialization/boost_array.hpp>
```

Adding it [makes it compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4620ce87aa32d72f), but let's also fix the function interface to remove the global:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3215d33e3a81bf7d)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/boost_array.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string save()
{
    std::ostringstream            ss;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa{ss};

    boost::array<int, 3> a{{0, 1, 2}};
    oa << a;

    return std::move(ss).str();
}

void load(std::string text)
{
    std::istringstream ss(std::move(text));
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia{ss};

    boost::array<int, 3> a;
    ia >> a;
    std::cout << a[0] << ", " << a[1] << ", " << a[2] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto text = save();
    load(text);
}
```

Prints

```
0, 1, 2
```

Comment: Thank you sehe! I've tried your solution and add <boost/serialization/boost_array.hpp>, but sadly it remains the same error. If I use the method make_array, it compiles OK. So I guess there is something wrong of my compile environment.

Comment: I found a 'trick' to solve this: according to line 116: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/serialization/access.hpp, to solve compile error of the example, remove "#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>" and it works!

Comment: Removing the other include makes no sense. It can't change a thing (as obviously the serialization header includes it). The warning about not including unsupported archive types is a different thing, completely unrelated (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9060459/85371) and [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#:~:text=all%20the%20file%20types%20used%20by%20the%20module%20by%20checking%20for%20definition%20of%20the%20header%20inclusion%20guards)). Regardless, just look at the live demo in my answer to see that it works.

Comment: Yes, I got your point. But a strange thing is,  the example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3215d33e3a81bf7d can not compile on my computer, unless I comment header  <boost/array.hpp> and <boost/serialization/array.hpp>. My compile command is 'g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lboost_serialization -I /usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/include/ -L /usr/local/lib/libboost1.65.1/lib/'. The directories are boost libraries compiled from source code. So I guess there is something    wrong in my compile environment.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the root cause of this error:
The version of gcc and g++ I use is tooooo old: g++ 4.8.0.
Default gcc and g++ version in Ubuntu 18.04 is 7.5.0

The reason why I use g++ 4.8.0, is because I want to install apollo autonomous driving toolkit in my Ubuntu.
And then I want to try LIO-SAM mapping toolkit in my Ubuntu too.
But the fatal error comes out, that LIO-SAM, and the dependencies like Boost, gtsam and ROS can not compile by g++ 4.8.0.

So be careful of your compile environment.